# how to combine multiple awk commands using different options

Tags: shell, awk

I need some help in joining the below 3 awk commands using different options.

- awk -F/ 'BEGIN {print "SPK REPO"} {print $7," ",$9}' - To extract 6th and 8th field
- awk -v RS=' ' 'BEGIN {print "log4j-version"} '/^1/''} - To extract the version in 13th field.
- awk -F'[][]' 'BEGIN {print "Timestamp"} {print $2}' - To extract datetime stamp from 13th field.

Input Text file format : /hosting/cbj/shared/master/jobs/TAIS/jobs/tais_aem_build/branches/feature-Dev/builds/214/log:[2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z] ch.qos.logback.classic.log4j 0 1.2.3 com.baml.tais.tais_aem_build:jar:6.4.0

I need to extract the 6th, 8th, 13th (date-timestamp), 13th (1.2.3 version) and print them into a csv file with headers.
Sample Output :

| SPK | REPO | log4j-version | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TAIS | tais_aem_build | 1.2.3 | 2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z |

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting then format your sample input and expected output as Code Blocks so we can copy/paste them to test with. Using `RS=' '` implies your input records can contain newlines so make sure to include at least 1 such case in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple delimiters

```
awk -F'/|\\[|] ?| ' '
   BEGIN{
      OFS=";"
      print "SPK","REPO","log4j-version","Timestamp"
   }
   {
      print $7,$9,$18,$15
   }
 ' file

SPK;REPO;log4j-version;Timestamp
TAIS;tais_aem_build;1.2.3;2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z
```

---

Or changing all delimiters to `/`

```
awk -F/ '
   BEGIN{
      OFS=";"
      print "SPK","REPO","log4j-version","Timestamp"
  }
  {
     gsub(/[][ ]/, "/"); 
     gsub("//", "/"); 
     print $7,$9,$18,$15
  }
' file

SPK;REPO;log4j-version;Timestamp
TAIS;tais_aem_build;1.2.3;2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z
```

---

Or using split

```
awk '
   BEGIN{
      OFS=";"
      print "SPK","REPO","log4j-version","Timestamp"
   }
   {
      n=split($1,a,"/")
      print a[7],a[9], $4, gensub(/.*\[(.*)\].*/,"\\1",1,a[n])
   }
 ' file

SPK;REPO;log4j-version;Timestamp
TAIS;tais_aem_build;1.2.3;2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z
```

Comment: Using multiple delimiters                                                                                            awk -F'/|\\[|] ?| ' '
   BEGIN{
      OFS=","
      print "SPK","REPO","log4j-version","Timestamp"
   }
   {
      print $7,$9,$18,$15
   }
 ' file

SPK,REPO,log4j-version,Timestamp
TAIS,tais_aem_build,,2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z                                                                  This works but the log4j-version does not get printed. Instead it leaves the space blank.

Comment: Using multiple delimiters :                                                                                                                                                                                                                awk -F'/|\\[|] ?| ' '
   BEGIN{
      OFS=","
      print "SPK","REPO","log4j-version","Timestamp"
   }
   {
      print $7,$9,$18,$15
   }
 ' file

SPK,REPO,log4j-version,Timestamp
TAIS,tais_aem_build,,2022-06-23T07:23:56.117Z                                                                  This works but the log4j-version does not get printed.

Comment: Change `$18` to `$19` or `$17` and try again